# show page numbers in Data View Web Part paging

Tags: xml, xslt, sharepoint-2007, dataviewwebpart

I'm working on SharePoint 2007.
On adding Pagination in the Data View Web Part, by default it shows something like '1-10'. ie the numnber of documents dispalyed. I wish to replace this with exact page number such as '1|2|3|4....' so that the User can directly navigate to any particular Page.
I tried to edit the XSLT by following this link:
http://blogs.msdn.com/b/cjwalker/archive/2005/05/28/422826.aspx

Steps I followed:

1. Find `<xsl:template name="dvt_1.navigation">` and add `<xsl:param name="Rows"/>` as the last param
2. Somewhere in the  that is output in this template

   `<tr><td colspan="2" class="ms-vb">
      <xsl:for-each select="$Rows">
         <xsl:if test="(position() mod $RowLimit) = 1">
            <a>
                 <xsl:attribute name="href">javascript: <xsl:value-of xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" select="ddwrt:GenFireServerEvent(concat('dvt_firstrow={',position(),'}'))"/>;</xsl:attribute>
                 <xsl:value-of select="((position() - 1) div $RowLimit) + 1"/></a>
                 <xsl:text xmlns:ddwrt="http://schemas.microsoft.com/WebParts/v2/DataView/runtime" ddwrt:nbsp-preserve="yes" disable-output-escaping="yes">&amp;nbsp;</xsl:text>
         </xsl:if>
      </xsl:for-each>
   </td></tr>`
3. Find `<xsl:call-template name="dvt_1.navigation">` and add `<xsl:with-param name="Rows" select="$Rows"/>` as the last param.

I followed exact steps but but it shows error that the webpart cant be rendered.
Can any body tell me whats missing in this code.

Thanks in Advance